# we don't know . . . unless

Tags: conjunctions, conditional-constructions, conditionals

Are the following sentences correct?

> We don't know how the word was used in the 13th century, unless we **could go** back in time.

> We don't know how the word was used in the 13th century, unless we **went** back in time.

Clearly, going back in time is currently an impossibility, so "unless we go back in time" doesn't seem correct. ESL grammar books haven't discussed the hypothetical (counterfactual) use of "unless" and this hypothetical use with a factual main clause.

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: I might express that by  
"We can't know how the word was used in the 13th century, unless we go back in time."

Comment: But going back in time is counterfactual; shouldn't that be expressed in the conditional?

Comment: You could say "Unless we could go back in time, we couldn't know...", but with "can't", I think it works with "unless we go..."

Comment: The problem with "we couldn't know" is it's not expressed as a fact. It is a fact that we **can't know** how the word was used in the 13th century. But if we try to match "we can't know" with "unless we go," we will notice that the latter is actually an impossibility, and thus should not be in the indicative. How do we resolve the dilemma?

Comment: It's the same as "unless the impossible happens", which has no problems of grammar or meaning.

Answer (score 1):

This would sound more natural to me:

> We ***can't*** know how the word was used in the 13th century, unless we ***go*** back in time.

To say that you *don't know something unless you do something* is less successful than saying that you ***cannot know unless you do something***. And I think *go* should be in the present as the verb in the main clause is in the present. However *went* is not wrong either, and it does put an emphasis on the fact that it is ***highly unlikely that we will go back***. However, one must be careful with emphasis, it can distract the attention of the reader from one's main point. To my mind a sentence like

> We don't know how the word was used in the 13th century, unless we went back in time.

is very ok, but just for a second there my mind lingered on ***went***, when the main meaning seems to be contained in the first clause. Unless your intent is to focus on the fact that ***we cannot go to the past***, I think it is alright to put *go* instead of *went*.

Answer (score 0):

Having the ability to go back does not equate to doing so. So the ability alone does not let us know what word was used in that century. To find the word we have to go back. So your first sentence fails. And if we go back, we clearly have the ability to go back, so your second sentence includes the possibility that we could go back - that we have the ability to do so. Your second sentence succeeds.

Comment: But even the said ability is an impossibility.

Comment: @Apollyon, In practice yes, but this is not about reality; it is about the use of language within an imagined circumstance. Reality does not matter in this case. We are not invited to discuss whether time travel is possible or not.

Comment: Reality does matter in the discussion of language. That's why irrealis and counterfactuality are all about.

Comment: @Apollyon Have you never read any fiction?

Comment: Fiction presents non-realty as if it were reality in order to look real. That's different from the case in hand.